# How do I merge two very close non-intersecting geometries?

Tags: graphics, geometry, interpolation

[image: Almost intersecting]

- Purple and Red are the input polygons/geometries.
- Green is the result I want. (I don't have a proper definition for how the resulting geometry needs to be defined at the discontinuity).
- I don't want to use a buffer operation (or polygon offsetting) as I think it might give me unexpected results when I expand the geometries and shrink them back.

**What I tried:**

- I'm thinking of getting the pair of edges with shortest distance and check if the distance is less than a threshold.
- Get the shortest edge in the pair and drawing lines from the vertices of this edge to intersect with the other geometry such that the length of the resulting line segments is the minimum.
- I feel like this approach is inelegant(not a proper interpolation) and not optimal.

---

- Need a proper way of interpolating the gap between the polygons in an optimized way.
- I want to avoid using a buffer method (or polygon offsetting) unless I'm certain it is a proper interpolation.

Comment: What are your data structures like? How are the shapes described in your program?

Comment: This operation is called a shrinkwrap if you want to search for it.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou, Shapes are stored as an array of points/vertices. I'll checkout shrinkwrap.

Comment: this might work for you. Recombine the points with a convex hull : https://discourse.threejs.org/t/making-a-geometry-from-points-how-to-shrink-wrap-a-convex-hull-around-some-points/5753/9

Comment: It didn't work for me. I tried the alpha-shape [demo](https://mikolalysenko.github.io/alpha-shape/index.html) for the points in the picture I posted. It might work if I have to use different values of alpha for different set of points. But that's isn't what I wanted.